# Alter txt file contents with BAT script

Tags: batch

I need to take a text files contents and sort them into a column and re-save the file.

The contents of the file look like this, all in one string....

```
core.jar:core-junit.jar:bouncycastle.jar:ext.jar:framework.jar:framework2.jar:telephony-common.jar:mms-common.jar:android.policy.jar:services.jar:apache-xml.jar:sec_edm.jar:seccamera.jar:scrollpause.jar:stayrotation.jar:smartfaceservice.jar:abt-persistence.jar:secocsp.jar:sc.jar
```

I need to make them look like this in one column...

```
core.jar:
core-junit.jar:
bouncycastle.jar:
ext.jar:
......etc
```

And just to make things more difficult for me, I dont always know what the names will be on the text.  I do know that there will always be a colon separating the names though.  So maybe there is a way to pull text between colons and save to new text in a single column?

EDIT**  Or, a script to change from row to column would work i think.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Windows batch, we're assuming? I'll work on something shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Input is `foo.txt` and output is `foobar.txt`.  I don't understand how the recursion works on the %%b variable, but it does on Windows 7 Pro regular command shell.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto afterfunctions

REM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file
:trimstring <therestVar> <inputVar>
(
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ("!%~2!") do (
        echo %%a
        REM echo %%b
        REM %%b is the rest of it. Now we need to call this function with just that string.
        call :trimstring result %%b
    )
)
(
    endlocal
    exit /b
)

:afterfunctions
for /f "delims=" %%x in (foo.txt) do set mystring=%%x
set thisstring=%mystring%
call :trimstring result mystring > foobar.txt
:eof
```